# Python: how to replicate the same row of a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

How can I copy each row of an array *n* times?

So if I have a `2x3` array, and I copy each row 3 times, I will have a `6x3` array. For example, I need to convert `A` to `B` below:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]])

B = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [4, 5, 6]])
```

If possible, I would like to avoid a `for` loop.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add what you have done by far and make sure to visit our [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help you improve your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If I read correctly, this is probably what you want assuming you started with `mat`:

```
transformed = np.concatenate([np.vstack([mat[:, i]] * 3).T for i in range(mat.shape[1])], axis=1)
```

Here's a verifiable example:

```
# mocking a starting array
import string
mat = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=(5,3))

>>> mat
array([['s', 'r', 'e'],
       ['g', 'v', 'c'],
       ['i', 'b', 'd'],
       ['f', 'g', 's'],
       ['o', 'm', 'w']], dtype='<U1')
```

Transform it:

```
# this repeats it 3 times for sake of displaying
transformed = np.concatenate([np.vstack([mat[i, :]] * 3).T for i in range(mat.shape[0])], axis=1).T

>>> transformed
array([['s', 'r', 'e'],
   ['s', 'r', 'e'],
   ['s', 'r', 'e'],
   ['g', 'v', 'c'],
   ['g', 'v', 'c'],
   ['g', 'v', 'c'],
   ['i', 'b', 'd'],
   ['i', 'b', 'd'],
   ['i', 'b', 'd'],
   ['f', 'g', 's'],
   ['f', 'g', 's'],
   ['f', 'g', 's'],
   ['o', 'm', 'w'],
   ['o', 'm', 'w'],
   ['o', 'm', 'w']], dtype='<U1')
```

The idea of this is to use vstack to concatenate each column to itself multiple time, and then concatenate the result of that to get the final array.

Comment: No, I want to copy the rows. So from your matrix I want arrive to a matrix of this kind:
[[s,r,e]
[s,r,e]
[s,r,e]
[g,v,c]
[g,v,c]
[g,v,c] and so on.

Comment: That's not what you said both in the question and in the comment you provided to @Kerem

Comment: Yes, because I don't ask to copy all the matrix, but each single row.

Comment: That's a relatively easy fix. but next time please include the example input and output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with integer positional indexing:

```
B = A[np.repeat(np.arange(A.shape[0]), 3)]

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v1=[3,2]
v3=v1[:]*10
print(v3)
```

Comment: This concatenates [3,2] for 10 times v1. I need to have [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]

Comment: Now I am using np.repeat(matrix[np.newaxis,:],10,0),but python clones the matrix ten times, and not each row.

Answer (score 0):

`np.repeat` is exactly what you are looking for. You can use the `axis` option to specify that you want to duplicate rows.

`B = np.repeat(A, 3, axis=0)`